# Given a Type T that satisfies T.isArray, is it possible to initialize a variable of type typeof(T).getElementType?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, types

When creating a method for type T, I realized that I wanted to recur on the rank of the Array. As far as I understand, this violates static typing, but is there a work around, since I technically do know the type that I am trying to create at runtime?

So I found the rank, but cannot declare variables of any type other than T, so I can't actually perform the recursion.

Another way to solve my problem would be to declare variable-dimensional arrays. Are either of these possible?

Thank you

edit: A problem example would be trying to read in a string input into a multi-dimensional array say "1* 2|2* 3$2* 3|3* 4" (with the delimiters *, | and $), I would like to create the 3 dimensional array {{{1,2}, {2,3}} {{2,3},{3,4}}} by first creating the innermost arrays and then working my way out recursively.

Comment: What does "recur on the rank of the Array" mean?

Comment: If you could [edit] your question to provide pseudo c# code to illustrate what you actually want to achieve, that would probably help.

Comment: So lets say the end goal is to convert a string into a 3d integer array, what I would like to do would be to split that into parts and then convert those parts separately into 2d integer arrays and so on until we just need to define how to input integers as arrays. Thus i use the terminology of "recurring on the rank of the array".

Comment: Do you know the rank of your array ahead of time? (Is it always 3D?) If you don’t know, how do you intend to process it?

Comment: I know the rank of the array ahead of time, but Its not always 3D.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. Reading directly into multidimensional array is pain unless you know size in advance... Did you consider making your life easier by unsing jagged arrays?

Comment: I would have never guessed what "recurring on the rank of the array" means, even after your explanation. It's always better to provide a clear explanation (plus code) rather than to invent terms.

Comment: And by clear explanation I mean the opposite of "So I found the rank, but cannot declare variables of any type other than T, so I can't actually perform the recursion." Can you clarify what you mean by that? Perhaps you could read [ask] too?

Comment: A “variable-dimensional array” is doable with a non-regular datatype: `class Array<T> { T items; Array<T[]> next; }` with the assumption that exactly one of `items` or `next` is null. Then the number of `next`s you look at before you find an `items` is the rank of the array found in the `items` at the end of the chain. Kind of tricky to code with tho, and it’s probably more efficient to represent your nested data as a flat array with some indexing arithmetic. (That’s how scientific computing systems do it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand the question, but what you said in the title, specifically:

> Given a Type T that satisfies T.isArray, is it possible to initialize a variable of type typeof(T).getElementType?

Is definitely possible:

```
var x = new [] { 1, 2};
if (x.GetType().IsArray) {
   var z =  Activator.CreateInstance(x.GetType().GetElementType());
   Console.WriteLine(z); // prints 0
}
```

**Update**
And in regards to parsing that heaps specific format you posted, you can do it like so:

```
var source = "1* 2|2* 3$2* 3|3* 4";
        
var res = source.Split("$", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
.Select(x => x.Split("|", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
.Select(x => x.Split("* ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
.Select(x => Int32.Parse(x))));

// Just print the data.     
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("$", res.Select(x => String.Join(";", x.Select(z => String.Join(",", z))))));
// Prints 1,2;2,3$2,3;3,4
```